# getting error: Class Magento\Indexer\Model\ResourceModel\Indexer\State\CollectionFactory does not exist

Tags: magento2, error, cli

When i run command for indexing

> php bin/magento indexer:info

Error was thrown

> Class Magento\Indexer\Model\ResourceModel\Indexer\State\CollectionFactory does not exist
>
> [Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]   Can't create
>   directory /var/www/html/var/generation/Magento/Indexer/Model/R
>   esourceModel/Indexer/State/.

I'm using magento 2.0.4, Linux server

Comment: give permissions to var /generation directory

Comment: wow , thanks it works. sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/var/generation/

Answer (score 3):

```
composer update and 

Please add permission.
```

Answer (score 1):

My www.test.com website on Ubunto 16.04 and nginx in the admin page had an error

> Class
>   Magento\Indexer\Model\ResourceModel\Indexer\State\CollectionFactory
>   does not exist

Turned out the folder
 `/var/www/test.com/html/magento/generated/code/Magento/Indexer` was owned by root and everything from there to 
`/var/www/test.com/html/magento/generated/code/Magento/Indexer/Model/Indexer/CollectionFactory.php`

fixed by changing owner to www-data like all the folders should have been:-

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/test.com/html/magento/generated
```

Answer (score 1):

In admin side I am getting

> Class Magento\Indexer\Model\ResourceModel\Indexer\State\CollectionFactory does not exist

so I tried

```
sudo php chown -R www-data:www-data my_magento2_folder/*
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a permission issue. Just give permissions to var /generation directory folders.
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/var/generation/